# Change the values stored in a json

Tags: javascript, html

I have a json data like this: It stores data generated from a vip.

```
[
   {
      "owner":"swapneil",
      "fleet_name":"RancorService",
      "creation_date":"09-03-2020",
      "environment":"RancorService/JP",
      "vip_port":80,
      "partition":"YES",
      "protocol":"HTTP",
      "monitor":"Consistent (http-ping)",
      "lbset":"Consistent",
      "predictor":"Consistent",
      "spillover":"Consistent",
      "vip_cka":"Consistent :(NO)",
      "max_conns":"Consistent : (36)",
      "vip_cipher":null,
      "vip_cip":"Consistent",
      "vip_tier":"Consistent(Tier1)",
      "vip_siloed":"Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
      "vip_globalized":"Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
      "vip_dedicated":"Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
      "vip_retail_tag":"Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
      "down_stat_flush":"Consistent :(ENABLED)",
      "vip_type":"Consistent (BACKEND)",
      "server_port":"Consistent",
      "vip_server_timeout":"Consistent",
      "vip_client_timeout":"Consistent",
      "persistent_method":"Consistent",
      "persistent_timeout":"Consistent"

},
   {
      "owner":"swapneil",
      "fleet_name":"RancorService",
      "creation_date":"09-03-2020",
      "environment":"RancorService/JP",
      "vip_port":443,
      "partition":"YES",
      "protocol":"TCP",
      "monitor":"NC",
      "lbset":"NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
      "predictor":"NC (leastconns,ROUNDROBINSHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN)",
      "spillover":"Consistent",
      "vip_cka":"Consistent :(NO)",
      "max_conns":"Consistent : (9000)",
      "vip_cipher":null,
      "vip_cip":"Consistent",
      "vip_tier":"Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
      "vip_siloed":"Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
      "vip_globalized":"Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
      "vip_dedicated":"Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
      "vip_retail_tag":"Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
      "down_stat_flush":"Consistent :(ENABLED)",
      "vip_type":"Consistent (BACKEND)",
      "server_port":"Consistent",
      "vip_server_timeout":"Consistent",
      "vip_client_timeout":"Consistent",
      "persistent_method":"Consistent",
      "persistent_timeout":"Consistent"

},
   {
      "owner":"swapneil",
      "fleet_name":"RegionAwareBaseLayer",
      "creation_date":"09-03-2020",
      "environment":"RegionAwareBaseLayer/NA",
      "vip_port":80,
      "partition":"YES",
      "protocol":"HTTP",
      "monitor":"Consistent (http-ping)",
      "lbset":"Consistent",
      "predictor":"Consistent",
      "spillover":"Consistent",
      "vip_cka":"Consistent :(NO)",
      "max_conns":"Consistent : (56)",
      "vip_cipher":null,
      "vip_cip":"Consistent",
      "vip_tier":"NC : >1 VIP's MISSING TIER-1 TAG",
      "vip_siloed":"Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
      "vip_globalized":"Consistent(GLOBALIZED)",
      "vip_dedicated":"Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
      "vip_retail_tag":"Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
      "down_stat_flush":"Consistent :(ENABLED)",
      "vip_type":"Consistent (BACKEND)",
      "server_port":"Consistent",
      "vip_server_timeout":"Consistent",
      "vip_client_timeout":"Consistent",
      "persistent_method":"Consistent",
      "persistent_timeout":"Consistent"

},
   {
      "owner":"swapneil",
      "fleet_name":"RegionAwareBaseLayer",
      "creation_date":"09-03-2020",
      "environment":"RegionAwareBaseLayer/NA",
      "vip_port":443,
      "partition":"NO",
      "protocol":"TCP",
      "monitor":"Consistent (ssl-ping)",
      "lbset":"Consistent",
      "predictor":"NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
      "spillover":"Consistent",
      "vip_cka":"NC : SHOULD BE DISABLED (YES)",
      "max_conns":"Consistent : (9000)",
      "vip_cipher":null,
      "vip_cip":"Consistent",
      "vip_tier":"Consistent(Tier1)",
      "vip_siloed":"Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
      "vip_globalized":"Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
      "vip_dedicated":"Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
      "vip_retail_tag":"Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
      "down_stat_flush":"Consistent :(ENABLED)",
      "vip_type":"Consistent (BACKEND)",
      "server_port":"Consistent",
      "vip_server_timeout":"Consistent",
      "vip_client_timeout":"Consistent",
      "persistent_method":"Consistent",
      "persistent_timeout":"Consistent"

},
   {
      "owner":"swapneil",
      "fleet_name":"RegionMappingService",
      "creation_date":"09-03-2020",
      "environment":"RegionMappingService/EU",
      "vip_port":80,
      "partition":"YES",
      "protocol":"HTTP",
      "monitor":"Consistent (http-ping)",
      "lbset":"Consistent",
      "predictor":"Consistent",
      "spillover":"Consistent",
      "vip_cka":"Consistent :(NO)",
      "max_conns":"Consistent : (16)",
      "vip_cipher":null,
      "vip_cip":"Consistent",
      "vip_tier":"Consistent(Tier1)",
      "vip_siloed":"Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
      "vip_globalized":"Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
      "vip_dedicated":"Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
      "vip_retail_tag":"Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
      "down_stat_flush":"Consistent :(ENABLED)",
      "vip_type":"Consistent (BACKEND)",
      "server_port":"Consistent",
      "vip_server_timeout":"Consistent",
      "vip_client_timeout":"Consistent",
      "persistent_method":"Consistent",
      "persistent_timeout":"Consistent"

},
   {
      "owner":"swapneil",
      "fleet_name":"RegionMappingService",
      "creation_date":"09-03-2020",
      "environment":"RegionMappingService/EU",
      "vip_port":443,
      "partition":"YES",
      "protocol":"TCP",
      "monitor":"NC",
      "lbset":"NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
      "predictor":"NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
      "spillover":"Consistent",
      "vip_cka":"Consistent :(NO)",
      "max_conns":"Consistent : (9000)",
      "vip_cipher":null,
      "vip_cip":"Consistent",
      "vip_tier":"Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
      "vip_siloed":"Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
      "vip_globalized":"Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
      "vip_dedicated":"Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
      "vip_retail_tag":"Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
      "down_stat_flush":"Consistent :(ENABLED)",
      "vip_type":"Consistent (BACKEND)",
      "server_port":"Consistent",
      "vip_server_timeout":"Consistent",
      "vip_client_timeout":"Consistent",
      "persistent_method":"Consistent",
      "persistent_timeout":"Consistent"

},
   {
      "owner":"swapneil",
      "fleet_name":"RegionAwareBaseLayer",
      "creation_date":"09-03-2020",
      "environment":"RABLIndexer/EU",
      "vip_port":80,
      "partition":"NO",
      "protocol":"HTTP",
      "monitor":"Consistent (http-ping)",
      "lbset":"Consistent",
      "predictor":"Consistent",
      "spillover":"Consistent",
      "vip_cka":"NC : SHOULD BE DISABLED (YES)",
      "max_conns":"MAX-CONNS WITH DEFAULT VALUE : 15",
      "vip_cipher":null,
      "vip_cip":"Consistent",
      "vip_tier":"Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
      "vip_siloed":"Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
      "vip_globalized":"Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
      "vip_dedicated":"Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
      "vip_retail_tag":"Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
      "down_stat_flush":"Consistent :(ENABLED)",
      "vip_type":"Consistent (BACKEND)",
      "server_port":"Consistent",
      "vip_server_timeout":"Consistent",
      "vip_client_timeout":"Consistent",
      "persistent_method":"Consistent",
      "persistent_timeout":"Consistent"

},
   {
      "owner":"swapneil",
      "fleet_name":"RegionMappingService",
      "creation_date":"09-03-2020",
      "environment":"RegionMappingService/JP",
      "vip_port":80,
      "partition":"YES",
      "protocol":"HTTP",
      "monitor":"NC",
      "lbset":"Consistent",
      "predictor":"Consistent",
      "spillover":"Consistent",
      "vip_cka":"Consistent :(NO)",
      "max_conns":"Consistent : (40)",
      "vip_cipher":null,
      "vip_cip":"Consistent",
      "vip_tier":"Consistent(Tier1)",
      "vip_siloed":"Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
      "vip_globalized":"Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
      "vip_dedicated":"Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
      "vip_retail_tag":"Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
      "down_stat_flush":"Consistent :(ENABLED)",
      "vip_type":"Consistent (BACKEND)",
      "server_port":"Consistent",
      "vip_server_timeout":"Consistent",
      "vip_client_timeout":"Consistent",
      "persistent_method":"Consistent",
      "persistent_timeout":"Consistent"

},
   {
      "owner":"swapneil",
      "fleet_name":"RegionMappingService",
      "creation_date":"09-03-2020",
      "environment":"RegionMappingService/JP",
      "vip_port":443,
      "partition":"YES",
      "protocol":"TCP",
      "monitor":"NC",
      "lbset":"NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
      "predictor":"NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
      "spillover":"Consistent",
      "vip_cka":"Consistent :(NO)",
      "max_conns":"Consistent : (9000)",
      "vip_cipher":null,
      "vip_cip":"Consistent",
      "vip_tier":"Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
      "vip_siloed":"Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
      "vip_globalized":"Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
      "vip_dedicated":"Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
      "vip_retail_tag":"Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
      "down_stat_flush":"Consistent :(ENABLED)",
      "vip_type":"Consistent (BACKEND)",
      "server_port":"Consistent",
      "vip_server_timeout":"Consistent",
      "vip_client_timeout":"Consistent",
      "persistent_method":"Consistent",
      "persistent_timeout":"Consistent"

}
]
```

and this is the function that makes a table of this data:

```
        function generateDynamicTable(myContacts){
    var noOfContacts = myContacts.length;

    if(noOfContacts>0){


        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.style.width = '50%';
        table.setAttribute('border', '1');
        table.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
        table.setAttribute('cellpadding', '5');


        var col = []; // define an empty array
        for (var i = 0; i < noOfContacts; i++) {
            for (var key in myContacts[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // CREATE TABLE HEAD .
        var tHead = document.createElement("thead");


        // CREATE ROW FOR TABLE HEAD .
        var hRow = document.createElement("tr");

        // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                var th = document.createElement("th");
                th.innerHTML = col[i];
                hRow.appendChild(th);
        }
        tHead.appendChild(hRow);
        table.appendChild(tHead);

        // CREATE TABLE BODY .
        var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
        for (var i = 0; i < noOfContacts; i++) {

                var bRow = document.createElement("tr");


                for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                    var td = document.createElement("td");
                    td.innerHTML = myContacts[i][col[j]];  //changed the code here
                    bRow.appendChild(td);
                }
                tBody.appendChild(bRow)

        }
        table.appendChild(tBody);


        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("demo");
        divContainer.appendChild(table);

    }
    }
```

I wanted to change values that starts with "Consistent" to "Consistent"
and values that stats with "NC" to "Non Consistent"
For this i added this code

```
            if(myContacts[i][col[j]].startsWith("Consistent"))
        {
            td.innerHTML = 'Consistent';
        }
        if(myContacts[i][col[j]].startsWith("NC"))
        {
            td.innerHTML = 'Non Consistent';
        }
```

But a it did not work and throws an error "TypeError: myContacts[i][col[j]].startsWith is not a function"
Can anyone provide a solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is an object, not a string, and objects don't have a `startsWith` method.

Try below working solution -

```js
var data = [{
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RancorService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RancorService/JP",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (36)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RancorService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RancorService/JP",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC (leastconns,ROUNDROBINSHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN)",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionAwareBaseLayer/NA",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (56)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "NC : >1 VIP's MISSING TIER-1 TAG",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionAwareBaseLayer/NA",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "NO",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (ssl-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "NC : SHOULD BE DISABLED (YES)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"

  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/EU",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (16)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"
  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/EU",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"
  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionAwareBaseLayer",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RABLIndexer/EU",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "NO",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "NC : SHOULD BE DISABLED (YES)",
    "max_conns": "MAX-CONNS WITH DEFAULT VALUE : 15",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"
  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/JP",
    "vip_port": 80,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "HTTP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "Consistent",
    "predictor": "Consistent",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (40)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"
  },
  {
    "owner": "swapneil",
    "fleet_name": "RegionMappingService",
    "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
    "environment": "RegionMappingService/JP",
    "vip_port": 443,
    "partition": "YES",
    "protocol": "TCP",
    "monitor": "NC",
    "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
    "predictor": "NC :SHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN",
    "spillover": "Consistent",
    "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
    "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
    "vip_cipher": null,
    "vip_cip": "Consistent",
    "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
    "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
    "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
    "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
    "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
    "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
    "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
    "server_port": "Consistent",
    "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
    "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
    "persistent_method": "Consistent",
    "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"
  }
]

function generateDynamicTable(myContacts) {
  var noOfContacts = myContacts.length;

  if (noOfContacts > 0) {


    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.style.width = '50%';
    table.setAttribute('border', '1');
    table.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
    table.setAttribute('cellpadding', '5');


    var col = []; // define an empty array
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfContacts; i++) {
      for (var key in myContacts[i]) {
        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          col.push(key);
        }
      }
    }

    // CREATE TABLE HEAD .
    var tHead = document.createElement("thead");


    // CREATE ROW FOR TABLE HEAD .
    var hRow = document.createElement("tr");

    // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      hRow.appendChild(th);
    }
    tHead.appendChild(hRow);
    table.appendChild(tHead);

    // CREATE TABLE BODY .
    var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfContacts; i++) {

      var bRow = document.createElement("tr");

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        var tempVal = (myContacts[i][col[j]] != null) ? myContacts[i][col[j]].toString() : "";
        td.innerHTML = tempVal;
        if (tempVal.startsWith("Consistent")) {
          td.innerHTML = 'Consistent';
        }
        if (tempVal.startsWith("NC")) {
          td.innerHTML = 'Non Consistent';
        }
        bRow.appendChild(td);
      }
      tBody.appendChild(bRow)

    }
    table.appendChild(tBody);


    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("demo");
    divContainer.appendChild(table);

  }
}

generateDynamicTable(data);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`startsWith` only exists for strings.
And you have data such as `"vip_cipher":null,`

So, before calling `x.startsWith()` you need to check that it's actually a string. Like `typeof x === "string"`

For example,

```js
if (typeof myContacts[i][col[j]] !== "string") {
    td.innerHTML = myContacts[i][col[j]].toString();
} else if (myContacts[i][col[j]].startsWith("Consistent")) {
  td.innerHTML = "Consistent";
} else if (myContacts[i][col[j]].startsWith("NC")) {
  td.innerHTML = "Non Consistent";
}
```